# Saving OrderID received from Payment Gateway

Tags: orders, payment-methods, payment-gateway, transaction

I'm working with a **payment gateway** from where after successful payment a **OrderId is received**. It is **similar to transaction id in Paypal**. I'm confused on how to make use of this information because this will be needed for refunding purpose.

Should I add any column to order model? Or there exists such feature where we can save such transaction key of a payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I will explain why solution from @Keyur Shah not so good.

- `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` doesn't have `setData` method, this method relates to `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` class. So your code depends on implementation but not on an abstraction.
- The `save` method is deprecated, the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::save` should be used instead

Now, possible approaches:

- Use `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::setExtOrderId` and `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::getExtOrderId` methods and order repository to do saving.
- Use `additional_information` for payment method, and store everything that you need. As [example](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html) how to use additional information.
- Use `extension attributes` to store complicated entities. You need to create own table and interfaces for your custom data. The [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html)

Your `OrderId` from the payment gateway can be saved by a [response handler](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/response-handler.html) if your payment integration based on Magento Payment Provider Gateway.
And **DO NOT** modify core tables.

Comment: I just gave a simple example how he can use this, I just mentioned that he can use `ext_order_id` attribute rather than creating an additional field. I agree with you that `save ` method is deprecated and we need to use Interface

Comment: And he should use only `ext_order_id ` attribute rather then `additional_information` from the question he only wants to save order id nothing else @Joni

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento creates an external attribute to save external order id(Just to save data from external payment provider), which is `ext_order_id` so you can save this value in this attribute.

later on, you can this value for further processing of an order

Updated answer after [@jones](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31707/joni-jones) answer but I just gave a simple explanation that you don't need to create any external attribute you can use OOTB attribute. And yes for saving this attribute you should use `Interface` pattern rather than `save`

Comment: Ok , I'll give it a try. Let me check.

Comment: Hello Keyur, I tried this. Where am I going to see this? Anywhere in frontend or backend?

Comment: No, you can not see this in frontend or backend, It is used for an Internal purpose. For ex. while online refund you can pass this id @Anime

Comment: So this field can be set by other payment methods as well. What if I have other payment methods as well?

Comment: then you can save your value in  `additional_information ` with `JSON` format, or you can create a new `attribute` just for only your payment method to avoid a complicated situation. :) @Anime